# Rotation of cube around x axis using clockwise

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have drawn cube using c++. I need to rotate around the axis in clockwise rotation.I found the method for rotation only for anti clockwise in the net.I need to calculate new points for the cube after rotation.is there any formula to calculate the new point?

Comment: C++ has no cubes ([sometimes](http://weegen.home.xs4all.nl/eelis/analogliterals.xhtml)). You need to specify many details, including what graphical toolkit you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the formula to rotate anti-clockwise then it should be pretty simple to rotate clockwise. If anticlock rotation is positive, then you just need to put negative theta in the equations to rotate clockwise.

For example, if anticlockwise rotation equation is:

```
x1 = x cos t - y sin t
y1 = x sin t + y cos t
```

Then clockwise rotation formula will be:

```
x1 = x cos (-t) - y sin (-t)
y1 = x sin (-t) + y cos (-t)
```

Using `cos (-t) = cos t` and `sin (-t) = -sin t`

```
x1 = x cos t + y sin t
y1 = -x sin t + y cos t
```